# How to debug resource timed out waiting for completion and gives no other error message

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

[CloudFormation Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeR38.png)

So while creating a ECS service in an AWS cluster it shows resource creation intiated and 3 hrs later shows resource timed out waiting for completion (CREATE_FAILED) and then shows ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS the follwoign service failed to create with no other messages.

I've searched up a lot but I'm unable to find a solution and CloudTrail also doesn't show anything

Comment: Do you have any Wait Policies in place that would stop the cluster from creating?

Comment: the cluster is created 
the service is not being created

Comment: Most probably the resource timed out because your ECS Containers were failing

Comment: but like what would be the reason